# I need a XOR output with two binary numbers as input in shell script

Tags: shell

I am trying to perform a XOR bitwise operation with two binary numbers in shell.
If, 
a=00001000
b=00110011
My output should be 00111011

Does Shell supports XOR operation for binary numbers?
I have also tried by downloading the logic.bc file from 
http://phodd.net/gnu-bc/code/logic.bc 
but it shows the error 
**Runtime error (func=(main), adr=270): Function xor not defined.**
Can anyone help me with the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Your numbers seem to be strings of binary digits, so you would need to convert those:

```
perl -e 'print (oct("0b".$ARGV[0])^oct("0b".$ARGV[1]))' 00111100 00001101
49
```

Or, if you want the answer in the same format:

```
perl -e 'printf("%.8b",oct("0b".$ARGV[0])^oct("0b".$ARGV[1]))' 00111100 00001101
00110001
```

**Original Answer**

Rather than introduce a dependency on downloading an obscure `bc` script, maybe consider leveraging something that is already built-in.

For example, Perl is built-in on Linux and macOS:

```
perl -e 'print ((0+$ARGV[0])^$ARGV[1])' 60 13
49
```

Likewise PHP:

```
php -r 'echo (0+$argv[1])^$argv[2];' 60 13
49
```

You may have `awk`:

```
awk -v x=60 -v y=13 'BEGIN{print xor(x,y)}'
49
```

Or Python:

```
python -c 'import sys; print(int(sys.argv[1])^int(sys.argv[2]))' 60 13
49
```

Comment: But here i working with two binary number. If i use the awk here i am getting the output in decimal. awk -v x=00001110 -v y=00110001 'BEGIN{print xor(x,y)}' it gives 109031 as output.

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and improve it so it shows what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have updated my answer and the second command starting with `perl ...` should be ideal for your needs.